# How to send email,sms notification from iPhone to Bluetooth LE device?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6

what services/profiles will i have to use to send email,sms notification from iphone to a bluetooth LE device.Is there any sample code???

Comment: Guess apple will first need to change the SDK for you to detect an new e-mail or SMS.

Comment: Is it possible from ios 6.where iphone will be acting as peripheral??

Comment: You could create a web service to do it for you... other than that I don't see any other solutions.

Comment: iOS 6 is still under NDA, meaning that we can't discus it here. But to my knowledge no.

Comment: Anirban Bhowmick: Are you able to implement any notifications in ios6.Could you please share your findings !

Comment: @rckoenes - is there a BT profile for emails? Like MAP is for SMS? Thanks.

Comment: Since Apple released ANCS in iOS 7, this should be possible now ?

Answer (score 1):

ANCS would be the answer in iOS 7, but I am not sure if the watch device can get the call number, content of message etc. That is sure that notification will be sent via ANCS.