# detect imessage or sms in iphone and send it to BluetoothLE watch

Tags: iphone, ios6, core-bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to send email,sms notification from iPhone to Bluetooth LE device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12197503/how-to-send-email-sms-notification-from-iphone-to-bluetooth-le-device)

I am designing a bluetoothLE watch.I want to detect any incoming imessage or sms in my iphone4s and send any notification message to my BluetoothLE watch that a new sms/imessage has arrived.Like it is done in metawatch or other smart watches.How can i acheive this?

Comment: Please stop asking the same question. This is the third time you've done so.

Comment: Anirban Bhowmick: Are you able to implement this?

Comment: This is question is quite useful,I also care about.